# It is possible to make point as one variable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

I trying to run this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n/\p in {b/(1,1),c/(2,1)}
        \node[draw,circle] (\n) at (\p) {};
\end{tikzpicture} % This is *not* working
```

And I got error.
I'm wondering if there is any way to put `\p` instead of `\x/\y`, i.e.:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n/\x/\y in {b/1/1,c/2/1}
        \node[draw,circle] (\n) at (\x,\y) {};
\end{tikzpicture} % This is working.
```

Thank you!

Comment: `\foreach \n/\p in {b/{1,1},c/{2,1}}` would work.

Comment: Working! Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to mask those `,` (using curly braces) that are *not* supposed to be a delimiter in the comma-separated list. So, the following would work:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n/\p in {b/{(1,1)},c/{(2,1)}}
        \node[draw,circle] (\n) at \p {};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Or:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n/\p in {b/{1,1},c/{2,1}}
        \node[draw,circle] (\n) at (\p) {};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Output of both MWE:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

PGFFor treats a coordinate (i.e. something starting with a `(`) at the beginning of an item specially and everything up to the next `)` is considered to be one element of an item.

Thus you can actually do

```
\foreach \p/\n in {(1,1)/b, (2,1)/c, (-10:2)/d}
```

which will allow you do mix “normal” coordinates in the *xy* coordinate system with those in the polar coordinate system or even use names of nodes/coordinates here.

In the example below, I'm adding `\n` as the content of the node so that the circles are easier to differentiate.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \foreach \p/\n in {(1,1)/b, (2,1)/c, (-10:2)/d}
    \node[draw, circle] (\n) at \p {\n};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]